# Using a listview inside a scrollview

Tags: android, android-widget

In my project I used `setcontentview(R.layout.first).here`. In a gallery I am displaying `second.xml`. In `second.xml` I have one `listview.when`. I am trying to scroll these `listviewitems` total screen scrolling, but it is not scrolling properly. Because outside we used scrollview. When I delete outside scrollview we cannot see the bottom of `listview`. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: mylayout files format:  this is first.xml:
<RelativeLayout>somedata<ScrollView><Gallery ></scrollview></RelativeLayout>
second.xml
<RelativeLayout1><RelativeLayout2></RelativeLayout2><ListView below of RelativeLayout2/></RelativeLayout>

Comment: Not Possible,though you can do one thing..add the below view in ListView footer using `lv.addFooterView(v, lv, isSelectable);` and remove the upper ScrollView.

Comment: how i can add footerview. how it will wrk. can u gve any example

Comment: actually iam getting data from database.those values displaying in listview

Comment: how i can solve my issue plz help me

Comment: I have posted one answer

Comment: any alternative without scrollview to scroll page?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ListView`'s [headers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29) and [footers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29) if you want to put some items only at the end/beginning of the `ListView`.

Watch [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=wDBM6wVEO70#t=2561s) video beginning from 42:40 it's really useful.

Answer (score 0):

ListView inside ScrollView is not possible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- here the picture info -->
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Depends on what you need. If you got a static Layout take ScrollView. If you got a (dynamically) list of items take ListView

Comment: plz gv some suugestion. i should scroll whole page, and when i come to Listview, listview items also should move. how i can do.

Comment: Perhaps if you place a Button in your ScrollView which opens a Popup-Window with the ListView.

Comment: actually iam displaying one image,that image size nearly 300dp. bottom of that image in listview iam displaying that image details.we should not use popup.

Comment: ok atleast can we scroll gallery in both directions.vertical and horizontal

Comment: Than i think the best way is using a ScrollView and place the Image details right under the picture in a LinearLayout and don't use ListView at all. I've placed some Code above.

Comment: how i can solve my issue. plz help me. i should scrollview whole page as well as listview.

Comment: any alternative without scrollview to scroll page?

Answer (score 0):

A list view will scroll automatically once it goes past its parents height or the ListViews maximum height

Answer (score 0):

If you put your ListView/any scrollable View inside the scrollView it will not work properly because when you touch the screen ,main focus of your touch is on parent view(scrollView ) not the child View (ListView).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
>  

 <ListView android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/all_workouts_list" 
    android:cacheColorHint="#ffffffff" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_above="@+id/add_workout_all_workout_list"></ListView>

<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"      
 android:id="@+id/add_workout_all_workout_list" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:text="Add Workout" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no any ready example with me,

So written a raw code like this as you asked in comment,

```
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)));
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        ll.addView(btn);
        lv.addFooterView(ll, null, true);
```

Comment: i used addfooter concept and linearlayout vertical concept also. i should ot display like that